# Strict px sizes on images in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have masonry style layout – http://reform.lt, when you scroll down images are preloaded with infinite scroll, the problem is that layout twitches when images are loaded. This is because there is no sizing on images and browser makes all alignments after adjacent images are loaded. After i added width and height to images, twitching stopped. I recored video without/with sizes – http://cl.ly/2K1a2B3P0R2Y

```
style="width: <?php echo $size[0];?>px; height: <?php echo $size[1];?>px;"
```

It would be fine, but images are not fluid anymore, so all responsiveness is ruined. Is there any simple solution to fix that?

Comment: Maybe you can use max-width instead of width.

Comment: I tried, doesn't help with twitching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add the height and width attributes to the images and add a class to make them responsive:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
```

And then add the following css in your stylesheet:

```
.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;      
}
```

Comment: @Leg Was just looking at your code on the URL added. Saw that you were trying to implement this. When you add the height and width attributes to the image, don't add px to the dimensions otherwise they don't work. And you can also add the max-width: 100%; height: auto; to 'figure img' in your stylesheet.

Comment: @vincente Problem solved. Thank you! As i'm just started learning webdev, one quick question for you: What does browser see when you don't add any units in sizing? It still counts them as pixels? It seems like so, but why no units can be responsive and pixels don't?

Comment: @Leg You're welcome. You can find more info on the img tag attributes here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox layout model](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You will need much less code/html.

For example, you can put *all* images in a single `div` with just a few CSS rules to get the same look that you have today. Something like:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that display: flex; isn't supported by IE9 and earlier versions. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @vicente - Correct. The page won't look as pretty in old IE, but it will display. And you can add a couple of fallback rules for old IE browsers to make it look nicer.